# Partial File Commit in Team Foundation

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

Is it possible to perform a "partial" or "patch" commit in Team Foundation? I have a single file with two lines that have been modified, but I only want to commit one of those lines. Git has this functionality in the "git add -p" command. Does TFS have something similar?

My problem more specifically is: my .proj file has changes to the database connections settings that I don't want committed to TFS (since this is a connection to a development database on my own dev computer). However, I have deleted a file in the project, so I want to commit the removal of the reference from the .proj file. I'm using Team Foundation Server 11 and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: For my specific problem I found out that I can set the "Configure deployment settings for:" dropdown in the project settings to "My isolated dev env" for those connection settings I want only on my computer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

You can undo one of those changes, commit the remaining one, then reapply the change you didnt' want to go.

OR

You could shelve your current changes, make the change to delete the file, commit that then unshelve your change set and keep working.